# Remove a product from category

Tags: magento-1.8, product, category

How do you programmatically remove a specific product from a specific category using?

Comment: what you mean, if your product is in 2 category so one  is deleted and other is remain ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: why do you not unset the category for product which you want to delete ?

Comment: Yeah by remove i mean unset, is there a method like setCategoryIds() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getCategoryIds()` to get existing categories, remove from that array your category in question and then use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::setCategoryIds($updatedCategoryIds)` method to update the product/category associations, then save the product by calling its `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::save()` method.

Comment: is there a way without looking for all categories and updating the product with their ids expect for the one i don't want to be associated with ?
Is there not any direct method ?

Comment: The method I have recommended you is the Magento way used by Magento codebase itself and that is the best way you can achieve your goal. Other methods either do the same thing that product model resource does, or imply working directly with database which is a no-no due to data corruption risk reasons but most importantly because you would need to write a lot more code than the recommended method has.